# Mongoose filter sending any data

Tags: javascript, api, express, mongoose

So I have this bit of code

```
// GET request for pokedex page
app.get("/pokedex", function (req, res) {
    Pokemon.find(function (err, pokemon) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(pokemon);
            res.render("pokedex", { pokemon: pokemon });
        }
    });
});
```

and it sends the data to the frontend just fine. The data also gets console.logged properly. The problem is when I add `{ information: { primaryType: "Grass" } },` before the callback, it doesn't send any data. The only thing that gets logged is empty arrays, but I'm trying to filter the data.

I am using JS, Node, Express, and EJS. I am also open to other ways to filter the data.

Model

```
[
  {
    information: {
      name: 'Bulbasaur',
      dexNumber: 1,
      primaryType: 'Grass',
      secondaryType: 'Poison',
      description: 'There is a plant seed on its back right from the day this Pokémon is born. The seed slowly grows larger.',
      devolvedForm: null,
      evolvedForm: 'Ivysaur'
    },
    stats: {
      health: 45,
      attack: 49,
      specialAttack: 65,
      defense: 49,
      specialDefense: 65,
      speed: 45
    },
    _id: 609cdab515102582ccf4e743,
    __v: 0
  },
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I added it to my post

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you need to use dot notation to filter:

```
Pokemon.find({ "information.primaryType": "Grass" }...
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I tried the dot notation before, but I hadn't used quotation marks. I haven't seen an example of it until now, not even in the mongoose docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find . Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you found the answer through a search, would you mind telling me where?

Comment: It's in mongodb docs, not mongoose: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation